# Watson Bluemix push error

Tags: ibm-cloud

I built the watsonqa.jar per [this tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-minecraft-watson-trs-4/). After running the command:

```
cf push -m 128M -c "node server.js"
```

I received the following error

```
FAILED
Start unsuccessful

TIP: use 'cf logs dialog-tool-hayday100-2147 --recent' for more information
minecraft@minecraft-VirtualBox:~/watsonspigotbluemix$ cf logs dialog-tool-hayday100-2147 --recent
 2016-03-11T20:19:57.67-0500 [STG/0]      ERR 
2016-03-11T20:20:03.86-0500 [STG/28]     OUT -----> Uploading droplet (59M)
2016-03-11T20:20:09.69-0500 [DEA/28]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 7db0f08f-ca12-4c82-9896-12a07e34dfa8
2016-03-11T20:20:21.15-0500 [App/0]      ERR module.js:338
2016-03-11T20:20:21.15-0500 [App/0]      ERR     throw err;
2016-03-11T20:20:21.15-0500 [App/0]      ERR           ^
2016-03-11T20:20:21.15-0500 [App/0]      ERR Error: Cannot find module '/home/vcap/app/server.js'
2016-03-11T20:20:21.15-0500 [App/0]      ERR     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
2016-03-11T20:20:21.15-0500 [App/0]      ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
2016-03-11T20:20:21.15-0500 [App/0]      ERR     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
2016-03-11T20:20:21.15-0500 [App/0]      ERR     at startup (node.js:129:16)
2016-03-11T20:20:21.15-0500 [App/0]      ERR     at node.js:814:3
2016-03-11T20:20:21.15-0500 [App/0]      OUT 
2016-03-11T20:20:21.26-0500 [DEA/28]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-11T20:20:21.32-0500 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 7db0f08f-ca12-4c82-9896-12a07e34dfa8 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"7db0f08f-ca12-4c82-9896-12a07e34dfa8", "version"=>"2a5148e5-0020-4817-a52b-21d7a7c01bab", "instance"=>"ca56895fbb5848ae81bb994fe8f5dfdb", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1457745621}
2016-03-11T20:20:21.32-0500 [API/8]      OUT App instance exited with guid 7db0f08f-ca12-4c82-9896-12a07e34dfa8 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"7db0f08f-ca12-4c82-9896-12a07e34dfa8", "version"=>"2a5148e5-0020-4817-a52b-21d7a7c01bab", "instance"=>"ca56895fbb5848ae81bb994fe8f5dfdb", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1457745621}
2016-03-11T20:21:20.69-0500 [DEA/147]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 7db0f08f-ca12-4c82-9896-12a07e34dfa8
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing: "cf push"? After building watsonqa.jar, you'll need to build docker image, push it to bluemix, and then run it.